# Export data honoring data masks

Tags: excel, excel-2010, data-masking

I have an Excel file that contains date-time information formatted like this:

```
10/25/2015 7:30:00 AM
```

I can apply a mask that can reformat the display to:

```
10/25/2015
```

Or

```
7:30:00 AM
```

But when I export this data it still displays in the long format.

Is there a way to force Excel to export the data in the truncated form?

I'm also trying to export to XML data in Windows. It would be great if Excel actually honors the data mask on export.

Comment: It would also be great to export the data as Saturday, October 25, 2015

Answer (score 0):

If you using only worksheet functions, the TEXT function might help

```
=TEXT(DateTimeValue, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

Depending on your specific requirements, you might want to create a new worksheet where you convert numeric data to a formatted text equivalent, then export the text.

You could also use VBA. For each cell C in the range of interest export

```
C.Text
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I will check it out and let you know. Thanks